# Generic function constrained to delegate types in c#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

In writing P/Invoke wrapper for a native dll, I found myself with a lot of code looking like this:

```
// Declare delegate types matching some callbacks in the dll
delegate void d1(T1, T1);
delegate void d2(T1,T2,T3);

// Some functions
void f1(T1 a, T2 b)
{
..
}

void f2(T1 a, T2 b, T3 c)
{
}
```

Then later,

```
// Marshal some instantiated delegates into IntPtrs to pass to native dll
IntPtr a = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new d1(f1));
IntPtr b = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new d2(f2));
```

So I end up with quite a lot of code looking like the above. I thought some refactoring using a generic function might be nice, something like this:

```
static void foo<T>(ref IntPtr ptr, T f)  where T: System.Delegate, new()
{
   ptr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new T(f));
}
```

Which would allow me to then write:

```
foo<d1>(a,f1);
foo<d2>(b,f2);
```

and so on. It doesn't compile! I tried to add some type constraints onto the function declaration, but can't get it to work. It's not that important to me in this instance, as the re-factoring is hardly very important, but I'm just curious to know how I'd do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot constraint a type to inherit from System.Delegate.  This limitation has frustrated me many times.  The only way around this for you is to constrain the delegate to be   a reference type and then do a nasty-ish cast:

```
    static void foo<T>(out IntPtr ptr, T f) where T : class
    {
        ptr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate( (Delegate)(object)f );
    }
```

You are not able to do a `new T(f)` because the `T:new()` constraint only allows a parameterless constructor.  The good news is that this is unnecessary as `T` is already a delegate type.  You would need to invoke it like:

```
    foo<d1>(out ptr, f1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to write a function that will take "any" delegate and return a delegate of the same type.  What one can do is write a family of generic functions for delegates of zero parameters, delegates of one by-value parameter, delegates of two by-value parameters, delegates of three by-value parameters, etc. along with, perhaps, delegates of one `ref` parameter, two `ref` parameters, a `ref` first parameter and a by-value second parameter, etc.  If one limits oneself to delegates that take by-value parameters, the amount of code duplication will likely be annoying but not totally hideous (five-fold duplication if you want to handle functions of up to four parameters, or nine-fold if you want functions of up to eight).  If you want to handle arbitrary combinations of `ref` and by-value parameters, the expansion becomes much worse (31 for functions of up to four parameters, or 511 for functions of up to eight).

My inclination would be to define a program which includes the code you want as a text resource with a few specialized "macro substitutions", and which when executed will expand out that text resource for all desired combinations of parameters and put the result into a textbox and select it, so as to allow it to be copied and pasted into a source file.  The resource would look something like:

```
public class ActionCombiner$0
{
    $1 _act1,_act2;
    void Invoke($2)
    {
        _act1($3);
        _act2($3);
    }
    ActionCombiner($1 act1, $1 act2)
    {
        _act1 = act1;
        _act2 = act2;
    }
    public $1 Create($1 act1, $1 act2)
    {
        var temp = new ActionCombiner$0(act1, act2);
        return temp.Invoke;
    }
}
```

The program would take the string resource and replace $0-$3 with various strings.  For $0, a list of generic type specifiers (e.g. `<T1,T2>`) or an empty string for the no-parameters case.  For $1, a delegate type that takes the parameters in question.  For $2, a list of parameters with types included (e.g. `T1 p1, T2 p2`).  For $3, a list of parameters without types included (e.g. `p1, p2`);.  Using such an approach, one could fairly easily provide generic functions for any desired pattern of parameters.